# d3 zoom: how do i prevent free dragging of the zoomed elements?

Tags: d3.js

```
const performZoom = (event) => {
  const transform = event.transform;
  d3.select(svgContainer.value).attr("transform", transform)
  store.zoomLevel = transform.k
}

  const container = d3.select(mapContainer.value)
  const zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", performZoom)
  container.call(zoom).on("wheel.zoom", null)
```

This is how I set up d3 zoom in my project (Vue3, that's why I use .value). The problem is that when before even I start zooming, I can take the whole element (a map) and move it outside the view, which should not be possible. I'll show you the problem on an image:

[image]

However, I have no idea how to do it. I tried .extent function on zoom element, like this:

```
.extent([[0,0], [svgContainer.value.clientWidth, svgContainer.value.clientHeight]])
```

but it seems not to do anything.
In other words: I want it to work the most obvious way, where when you zoom, then you can see all the parts of the element (the map) by dragging it, but you can't drag to the outside of the element.
Can I get any help with that?

Answer (score -1):

See translateExtent() - https://d3js.org/d3-zoom#zoom_translateExtent

```
const performZoom = (event) => {
  const transform = event.transform;
  d3.select(svgContainer.value).attr("transform", transform)
  store.zoomLevel = transform.k
}

  const container = d3.select(mapContainer.value)
  const zoom = d3.zoom()
       .scaleExtent([1, 10])
       .translateExtent([[-svgContainer.value.clientWidth / 2, -svgContainer.value.clientHeight / 2], [svgContainer.value.clientWidth / 2, svgContainer.value.clientHeight / 2]])
       .on("zoom", performZoom)
  container.call(zoom).on("wheel.zoom", null)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to improve your answer. Text should be written in English and there should be some elaboration on the solution as references can break.